# Cocoa, how to select text in a NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

I know this must be very simple... but I'm searching for about 30 mins and didn't find anything...
How do you select programmatically all the text in a NSTextView?
Thanks for your help
Massy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it, I'm posting the solution in case someone else needs to know how to do it:

```
[myTextView selectAll:self];
```

Comment: Yep, this is better than my answer.